# How to connect file inbound/outbound adapter and http inbound/outbound adapter or gateway in spring integration?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-dsl

I am developing a service adapter which will poll directory/subdirectories files , and parse that file using spring batch , but I am not understanding flow of file adapter +spring batch parser + http adapter connectivity , please suggest me better approach . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Hareram Giri   It will be helpful to have more information in your question in order to get great answers, such as what you have tried, and in what way it did not work.  Perhaps review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have completed spring batch parser , file inbound adapter with polling , and http inbound/outbound adapter separately . Now I want to connect all module to complete my application.

Comment: You should read the [Spring Integration Reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) and come back here if you have a specific question.

Comment: @gary Russel sir , I have read Reference manual but not getting how to connect file inbound adapter to http outbound adapter and spring batch parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good examples of using file inbound channel adapters, channels to connect components and integration with Spring Batch [here](https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample).